# Return a new array with all values except the first, adding 7 to each

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, return, addition

How to return a new array with all values except the first, adding 7 to each
For example, addSevenToMost([1, 3, 5]) should return [10, 12]

I tried

```
let arr = [1, 3, 5];

function addSevenToMost(arr) {
  let except = 0;
  const newArr = arr.filter((value, index) => index !== except);
  return newArr;
}
```

I only managed to get the new array values except the first, now I don't know how to add 7 to each.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 5];

let result = arr.slice(1).map(e => e + 7)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 5]
const result = arr.slice(1).map(item => item + 7)
console.log(result)
```